# Computing Eigenvectors from eigenvalues by making Symmteric Matrix from $X$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

I need to find out the eigenvectors of the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & X \\
X^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here it is given that $X$ is a matrix of shape m x n. The eigenvectors of the matrix need to be represented as singular vectors of X.

I tried by doing it using individual elements but it did not really work and the expression has become very complicated. Also, I don't know how to multiply block matrices

Comment: Hint: $\begin{bmatrix}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
U\\
V
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
AU+BV\\
CU+DV
\end{bmatrix}$ (if the sizes of the blocks are compatible).

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an aswer due to length.

Let $M=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{X}\\\mathbf{X}^T&\mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix}$. Note that $M^TM = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{XX}^T&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\end{bmatrix}$ and eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $M^TM$ are constructed by eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\mathbf{XX}^T$ and $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$, which will yield singular values/vectors of $\mathbf{X}$.

---

Other form is based on the definition, and using properties of the determinant of block matrices. Eigenvalues of $M$ are the solutions to $\det(M-\lambda I_{m+n})=0$. As the identity is invertible by definition, we can [write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant)
$$\begin{align}\det\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda\mathbf{I}&\mathbf{X}\\\mathbf{X}^T&-\lambda\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix}&=\det(-\lambda\mathbf{I}_n)\det\Big(-\lambda\mathbf{I}_n+\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{I}_m\mathbf{X}\Big)\\
&=(-\lambda)^n\det\Big(-\lambda\mathbf{I}_n+\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\Big)\\
&=\det\Big(\lambda^2\mathbf{I}_n-\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\Big)=0\\
\end{align}$$
and you'll also get $\det\Big(\lambda^2\mathbf{I}_m-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T\Big)=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = USV^T$ be an SVD, then
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & X\\X^T & 0\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}0 & USV^T\\VS^TU^T & 0\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}U&0\\0&V\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & S\\S^T & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}U^T&0\\0&V^T\end{pmatrix} = \tilde{U}\tilde{S}\tilde{U}^T.
$$
Can you finish from here? (Hint: diagonalize $\tilde{S}$ using a block matrix of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}I_m & I_{m,n}\\-I_{n,m} & I_n\end{pmatrix}$, where $I_{m,n}$ is an m-by-n matrix with ones on its main diagonal and the rest zeros, and $I_m$ is the identity of size m).